# is this class reading a file thread safe?

Tags: java

Could someone review this code to see if it's thread safe?

```
public class FileLinesSorter {   
private CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

/**
 * The lines
 */
private List<String> lines;

/**
 * Read files from the file paths
 * @param filePaths the list of file paths
 * @throws IOException on I/O error
 */
public void readFiles(String[] filePaths) throws IOException {
    lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String filePath : filePaths) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            // File does not exist. Log it.
            continue;
        }
        List<String> fileLines = readFile(file);
        lines.addAll(fileLines);
    }
    if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
        Collections.sort(lines);
    }
    startSignal.countDown();
}

/**
 * Read a single file
 * @param file  the file
 * @return  the file content
 * @throws IOException  on I/O error
 */
private List<String> readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
        reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            contents.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (fileReader != null) {
            fileReader.close();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    return contents;
}


public Iterator<String> getIterator() {
    try {
        startSignal.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines.iterator();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] filePaths = {"C:\\Works\\files\\example-1 copy.txt", "C:\\Works\\files\\example-2 copy.txt"};
    FileLinesSorter sorter = new FileLinesSorter();
    sorter.readFiles(filePaths);
    Iterator<String> lines = sorter.getIterator();
    while (lines.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(lines.next());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion this is not thread-safe. My understanding of thread-safe means that two threads can call methods on the same instance of this class at the same time and the class will behave as expected. This is not true for this class.

Consider this:

Thread 1 calls `readFiles()` which results in this line being called:

```
lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now imagine a second thread also calls `readFiles()` before the first thread finishes. This line is called again:

```
lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You have now overwritten the first variable with the second variable.

The first thread will call `lines.addAll(fileLines)` which will actually be using the second `lines` variable. This is probably not what you want.

The simplest fix is to add the `synchronized` keyword to the method signature. This will of course slow it down because the second call will wait for the first one to finish.

You should make `readFiles()` instantiate its own `List` and return its own instance of it. Then remove the private-level lines variable.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, the read code itself is thread safe, but the iterator method should not be public. 
The problem is that your implementing the Iterable interface. 
I think this is a bad design. 
You should not implement Iterable here, but rather have a method returning an Iterable of String object, which will return an Iterable object only after you complete reading the file. 
 This way, you can have a functionality of reading a file, and providing an iterable to its content. 
I suggest the following: 
A. Have a class called MyFileReader 
B. Have the field you defined above for keeping the lines.
C. Have a [CountdownLatc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)h object - call this field lock. Have it initialize with the value of 1. 
D. Your readFiles method should perform countDown once the file is read. 
E. Define a getIterator method which will create an iterator for the lines field, but prior to the creation, it will call lock.await() - this means this method will wait until the file is completely read. 
I hope it is more clear. I really should undestand how to embed code. I don't get it yet :(

Comment: Could you modify it so that I can get a better understanding?

Comment: I think what he is saying is do not implement Iterable.  Just have a method `getLines()` that returns lines, or a method `getLinesIterator()` that returns `lines.iterator()` and _only does so after the file is completely read_.

Comment: Exactly, I am newbie to stackoverflow and I dont know how to embed code. I will try to modify this.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the file reading itself is threadsafe, the read data is not.

Your `iterator()` method is public and while a thread is reading the file, another thread could call the `iterator()` method and get ConcurrentModificationException.(as ArrayList is fail-fast).

Comment: does it mean that the client (whoever calls this class) has to take care of thread safe instead of FileLinesSorter?

Comment: not necessarily, you can use a concurrent version of list like ConcurrentLinkedQueue